# Xpath in PHP with OTA standards

Tags: php, xml, xpath, namespaces

I have basic knowledge about the use of Xpath in PHP, but I'm having some troubles with a specific case and I think that the problem is in the standards.

This is the snippet of the XML and it's based on the [OTA standards](http://opentravel.org/Default.aspx):

```
<SendHotelResResult xmlns:a="http://schemas/Models/OTA" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:RoomRates>
         <a:RoomRate>
             <a:EffectiveDate>2015-11-13T00:00:00</a:EffectiveDate>
             <a:ExpireDate>2015-11-15T00:00:00</a:ExpireDate>
             <a:RatePlanID>25</a:RatePlanID>
             <a:RatesType>
                 <a:Rates>
                     <a:Rate>
                         <a:AgeQualifyingCode i:nil="true"/>
                                 <a:EffectiveDate>2015-11-13T00:00:00</a:EffectiveDate>
                         <a:Total>
                             <a:AmountAfterTax>0</a:AmountAfterTax>
                             <a:AmountBeforeTax>260.00</a:AmountBeforeTax>
                             <a:CurrencyCode>EUR</a:CurrencyCode>
                          </a:Total>
                     </a:Rate>
                     <a:Rate>
                         <a:AgeQualifyingCode i:nil="true"/>
                             <a:EffectiveDate>2015-11-14T00:00:00</a:EffectiveDate>
                         <a:Total>
                             <a:AmountAfterTax>0</a:AmountAfterTax>
                             <a:AmountBeforeTax>260.00</a:AmountBeforeTax>
                             <a:CurrencyCode>EUR</a:CurrencyCode>
                         </a:Total>
                     </a:Rate>
                 </a:Rates>
             </a:RatesType>
             <a:RoomID>52</a:RoomID>
             <a:Total>
                 <a:AmountAfterTax>546.00</a:AmountAfterTax>
                 <a:AmountBeforeTax>520.00</a:AmountBeforeTax>
                 <a:CurrencyCode>EUR</a:CurrencyCode>
             </a:Total>
         </a:RoomRate>
     </a:RoomRates>
</SendHotelRes>
```

*What I want*:

1. Get a specific `<RoomRate>` tag based on the element `<RoomID>`.
2. Get the global RoomRate `<Total>` tag. I don't want the `<Total>` tag that is inside the `<Rate>` tag. This is the reason why I'm using the xpath rather than a simple `getElementsByTagName('Total')`. I don't know if the OTA standards has some approach to differentiate the Total tags.

My attempts until now:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$response = $dom->load($xmlSendHotelRes);
$roomID = '52';
$roomRatesTag = $response->getElementsByTagName('RoomRates')->item(0);
$prefix = $roomRatesTag->prefix;
$namespace = $roomRatesTag->lookupNamespaceURI($prefix);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace($prefix, $namespace);
$roomRateTotal = $xpath->query("//RoomRate[RoomID=$roomID]/Total", $roomRatesTag, true);
```

I already tried with and without `$roomRatesTag` as context and also other expressions like:
 `./RoomRate[RoomID=$roomID]/Total`, `//RoomRate[RoomID=$roomID]/Total`, `//RoomRate/[RoomID=$roomID]/Total`,`//RoomRate[RoomID=$roomID]/Total` and `//RoomRate/RoomID[text() = $roomID]/../Total` but any of them works.

Actually, even `$roomRate = $xpath->query("//RoomRate");` returns a empty DOMNodeList, so, I don't know what I doing wrong and I'm thinking about the problem in the standards with 2 identical tags in different places, although this not make much sense.

Are there some other expressions that I need to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fetching the namespace from the document.

```
$prefix = $roomRatesTag->prefix;
$namespace = $roomRatesTag->lookupNamespaceURI($prefix);
```

But this is not necessary or a good idea. You know that the document uses OTA, so you know the namespace is `http://schemas/Models/OTA`.

The prefix is just an alias for the actual namespace value the following 3 XML example all resolve to a node `{http://schemas/Models/OTA}RoomRates`

- `<a:RoomRates xmlns:a="http://schemas/Models/OTA"/>`
- `<ota:RoomRates xmlns:ota="http://schemas/Models/OTA"/>`
- `<RoomRates xmlns="http://schemas/Models/OTA"/>`

Your Api has to look for nodes inside the namespace.

One possibility is to use the `*NS` (namespace aware) methods.

```
$response->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://schemas/Models/OTA', 'RoomRates')->item(0);
```

The other is to use Xpath and register prefixes for the namespaces. This can be the prefixes from the document, or different ones.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($xmlSendHotelRes);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('ota', 'http://schemas/Models/OTA');

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate(
    'string(//ota:RoomRates/ota:RoomRate[ota:RoomID=$roomID]/ota:Total)')
  )
);
```

For a location path, `DOMXpath::evaluate()` would return a `DOMNodeList` but with `string()` it casts the first found node into a string and returns it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a prefix (that you registered) and I think you want to start your path with `.//` and not with `//` if you want to search relative to the context node, so try `".//a:RoomRate[a:RoomID=$roomID]/a:Total"`